# What is the benefit of using a local variable?

Tags: c#, variables, properties

I keep seeing examples online, where there is a property of an element within a method that is copied to a local variable before use. For example, something like this (from Microsoft's `StackPanel` source code):

```
UIElementCollection children = arrangeElement.InternalChildren;

...

for (int i = 0, count = children.Count; i < count; ++i)
{
    UIElement child = (UIElement)children[i];
    if (child == null) { continue; }

    ...
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what the benefit of doing that is (if there is one), rather than accessing the property directly each time, like this?:

```
for (int i = 0, count = arrangeElement.InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
{
    UIElement child = (UIElement)arrangeElement.InternalChildren[i];
    if (child == null) { continue; }

    ...
}
```

Clearly, it saves a few characters on the screen, but that's not much of a reason to do this. Also, I understand why we might want to do this with a long running method, as a form of caching:

```
double value = GetValueFromLongRunningMethod();

...

for (int i = 0; i < someCollection.Count; i++) DoSomethingWith(value);
```

But I see this done with properties a lot and wonder why. Here's another commonly found example from the internet to do with virtualization:

```
IItemContainerGenerator generator = this.ItemContainerGenerator;
GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(firstVisibleItemIndex);
```

Why do that instead of this?:

```
GeneratorPosition position = 
    this.ItemContainerGenerator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(firstVisibleItemIndex);
```

Finally, if this is done for the same reason that we might cache the result of a long running method, then how are we supposed to know which properties need to be accessed in this way?

Comment: Readability....

Comment: You're talking about `online examples`, so the answer is readability.

Comment: What if the property is expensive to be called? Remember that properties are methods ...

Comment: Easier to read, write and often even better performance. (Which is a minor point)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but considering some property/field chain that has no relevant cost and the local variable is assigned and never modified, so that it's just an extra reference with readability as only benefit, I think the compiler would optimize it out nullifying its cost

Comment: @rzippo, those were my exact thoughts initially, and why I asked the question.

Comment: @DodgerThud, the first example is from Microsoft's `StackPanel` class, which until recently was private, and so not written for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @WPFguy Being private does not mean that is not meant for demonstration purposes. You're still talking about "examples" and that's what they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, it avoids calling `.InternalChildren` lots of times. This *could* be a small but noticeable reduction of virtual calls (since it is used in a loop), but in some cases it might be much more significant. In some cases, a property that returns a collection or array might allocate *every time it is called*; `DataRow.ItemArray` is a classic example of this - so it is *actively harmful* to call it each time. An additional consideration is that even if it returns the same array each time it is called, there is JIT magic that happens to elide bounds checking, but it'll only work if the JIT can see that you are iterating a single array for the entire duration. If you stick a property accessor in the middle: this won't be obvious and the bounds check removal won't happen. It also might not happen if you've manually hoisted the upper bound!

Side note: if it *isn't* an array, then `foreach` would probably *usually* be preferable, and there *would not* be any advantage to introducing a local, due to how `foreach` works internally.

---

Note: since you're using `.Count` vs `.Length`, this definitely isn't an array, and you should probably simplify to:

```
foreach(UIElement child = in arrangeElement.InternalChildren) {...}
```

or

```
foreach(var child = in arrangeElement.InternalChildren) {...}
```

Not only does this remove this question completely, but it means that the type's own iterator (which might be an optimized struct iterator, or might be a simple `IEnumerable<T>` class, such as a compiler-generated iterator block) can be used. This usually has more direct access to the internals, and thus bypasses a few indirections and API checks that indexers require.

Comment: @bommelding indeed; I was talking about the `arrangeElement.InternalChildren` vs `children` usage, but you're absolutely right: if this is an array, we should not attempt to optimize the `.Length` usage, but then: maybe the the fact that they're using `.Count` rather than `.Length` tells us it definitely isn't an array... will add an edit

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Marc. You make some interesting points. But I should like to remind you that that code is from the `StackPanel` class and has not been written by me.

Comment: @WPFguy I'm trying to answer in the most general terms that don't depend on who wrote the code, or what the exact scenario is...

Answer (score 1):

> Why do that instead of this?:
>
> ```
> GeneratorPosition position =
>  this.ItemContainerGenerator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(firstVisibleItemIndex);
> ```

Let's get very abstract about this:

1. We get a generator. That apparently is `this.ItemContainerGenerator` for now, but that could change.
2. We use it. Only once here, but usually in multiple statements.

When we later decide to get that generator elsewhere, the usage should stay the same.

The example is too small to make this convincing, but there is some kind of logic to be discerned here.

Comment: That's a fair point. But programming for what *might* be is generally not a good idea, is it?

Comment: A lot of architecture is aimed at changes that _might_ happen.  And they always do happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

It might be fruitful in some cases like when you have to

- debug some piece of code and you need to instantly see the value of variable
- do a few operations at a time with an object, which requires casting - as result you cast it once
- and sometimes, when you use value type objects this kind of making a local copy gives you an opportunity to not change the value of class' property